# Add padding to CubeSpline interpolation curve

Tags: python, scipy, spline, spatial-interpolation

I have the a set of points and I pass a curve through them, using `scipy` `CubeSpline`, I really would like to know how can I add padding from outside, so that the curve is fitting the flow of the points but they are always inside it by some factor, as shown in this image, where what I have is the blue line and what I need to get is the red curve [image: interpolated curve]

```
def visualize_trajectory(points):
    points = np.array(points)
    distance = np.cumsum(np.sqrt(np.sum(np.diff(points, axis=0)**2, axis=1)))
    distance = np.insert(distance, 0, 0)/distance[-1]

    interpolations_methods = ['cubic']
    alpha = np.linspace(0, 1, 25)
    interpolator = CubicSpline(distance, points, axis=0)
    interpolated_points = {}
    for method in interpolations_methods:
        interpolator = CubicSpline(distance, points, axis=0)
        interpolated_points[method] = interpolator(alpha)

    plt.figure(figsize=(7, 7))
    plt.gca().invert_yaxis()
    for method_name, curve in interpolated_points.items():
        plt.plot(*curve.T, '-', label=method_name)

    plt.plot(*points.T, 'ok', label='original points')
    plt.axis('equal')
    plt.legend()
    plt.xlabel('x')
    plt.ylabel('y')
    # plt.show(block=False)
    plt.show()
    plt.close()
```

Comment: 1. You posted 3 questions within an hour. While there is no question limit, it doesn't make sense why you're asking more questions when you haven't addressed the comments on some of your previous questions (namely, your other questions are missing reproducible examples). 2. I edited the tags on your other questions, but please read the tags before using them--you've been using the [tag:python-3.x] tag, which (if you read the description) should only be used for questions specifically pertaining to python 3.

Comment: I agree with you that I should have used python as a tag instead of python3, but I do not think saying "it does not make sense" for asking more questions is appropriate, I have different questions and they should be addressed in different threads, Who said that one needs to wait for a previous question to be answered so that I get the right to ask the next one? Sorry, but asking a question does not make me in a vulnerable position if you think so

Comment: You're missing my point. What "doesn't make sense" is that when you ask a question you should be ready to address comments. Posting more questions shows you're on the site but ignoring comments. Please read this post on [how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) (note the "Help others reproduce the problem" and "Respond to feedback after posting"). As I said, there is no rule against asking multiple questions, but I could tell that the questions need improvement to be answerable--there's a reason you have 3 open (unanswered) questions and I'm trying to help.

Comment: So I stand by what I said. I was trying to help you, but you don't seem to want help.

Comment: Thank you, I understand your position, but I really did my best within my capabilities, I have posted the code I wrote and the image for the clarification to what I need, for other questions, you might be right, but I am doing my best

Comment: For this question, your example is not self-contained (it is not a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)). Take the code out of a function, provide the points, and include the imports.

Comment: There may be a solution to this problem using Shapely - you could turn your points into a LineString, then [buffer](https://shapely.readthedocs.io/en/stable/reference/shapely.buffer.html) those points out to some distance. However, this produces a polygon where the edges are a fixed distance from your line, on all sides, in contrast to your desired solution where the edges are below and to the left.